# Changing parameters in sunpy tutorial throws an error - is this a bug?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, download, astropy

This is a follow-up question to [this question in the astronomy SO](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/47179/how-to-access-the-raw-time-series-dataset-of-goes-x-ray-flux/47180#47180).

Following [this example in sunpy](https://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/generated/gallery/acquiring_data/goes_xrs_example.html#sphx-glr-generated-gallery-acquiring-data-goes-xrs-example-py) (very similar to the answer in the linked post above), I am trying to access and download a time-series dataset spanning a few decades of X-Ray flux (XRS). The parameters `tstart` and `tend` define the boundaries of the range of datetimes to be considered.

Using sunpy 3.0.1, the following code snippet works successfully:

```
import datetime
from sunpy import timeseries as ts
from sunpy.net import Fido
from sunpy.net import attrs as a

tstart = datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 21, 1) # "2020-06-21 01:00"
tend = datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 21, 23) # "2020-06-21 23:00"
result = Fido.search(a.Time(tstart, tend), a.Instrument("XRS"), a.goes.SatelliteNumber(16))
goes_16_files = Fido.fetch(result)
goes_16 = ts.TimeSeries(goes_16_files, concat=True)
goes_table = goes_16.to_table()
goes_table.write('goes_16.csv', format='csv')
```

The example above gets observations spanning almost a full day (`tstart - tend` ~ 1 day). But I want the full dataset that spans years/decades; I plan to repeat the above procedure for all GOES satellites (not just number 16). From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GOES_satellites), I found that GOES-16 became operational at 19 November 2016, 23:42 and is still active (ie, never retired). Replacing `tstart` and `tend` with the corresponding range in the code will throw an error instead of running successfully (as shown below, using the same imports as above):

```
tstart = datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 19, 23, 59, 59)
tend = datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 21, 23) #datetime.datetime.now() # "2020-06-21 23:00"
result = Fido.search(a.Time(tstart, tend), a.Instrument("XRS"), a.goes.SatelliteNumber(16))
goes_16_files = Fido.fetch(result)
goes_16 = ts.TimeSeries(goes_16_files, concat=True)
goes_table = goes_16.to_table()
goes_table.write('goes_16_re.csv', format='csv')


Files Downloaded:   7%|█▌                   | 89/1227 [01:07<14:22,  1.32file/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/T123/Desktop/testme123.py", line 11, in <module>
    goes_table = goes_16.to_table()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_table'
```

In the code blocks above, the only thing that changed is the parameter `tstart`.

Is this a bug in sunpy? Or am I doing something incorrectly? In case it is relevant (since [some issues "appear" to be platform-specific](https://github.com/sunpy/sunpy/issues/5300)), I am running python 3.9 on macOS BigSur 11.2.1.

PS: I put `astropy` as a tag for this question because sunpy relies on astropy for some of their functionality (and because there is no `sunpy` tag). If there are more appropriate tags for this question, feel free to edit them in/out.

Comment: The error says that `goes_16` is a `list` so have you tried printing it out for inspection? Generally, this kind of explorative coding benefits from using an interactive shell (or Jupyter notebook) instead of a script file.

Comment: I have tried printing the list; it appears as a container of 90 entries that look like `<sunpy.timeseries.sources.goes.XRSTimeSeries object at 0x7ffe57b99190>` (but with different addresses in memory for each entry). I am confused because sunpy is internally casting it to a list, and the method works for other ranges of datetimes. Because of this, I'm not sure how to approach this error. Also, these 90 entries are shown and the error is raised when less than 20% of the files have been downloaded using `Fido`.

How might an interactive shell help in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/api/sunpy.timeseries.TimeSeries.html#sunpy.timeseries.TimeSeries) describes, `ts.TimeSeries` returns a list unless the `concatenate` parameter is `True`. Your code includes the differently named `concat` parameter which likely won't get picked up.